# Differentiate class and object in Python type hints

Tags: python, python-typing

[Django's `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save) sends a model class argument – `sender` – along with the actual instance being saved – `instance`.

Is there a way to differentiate between the two in type hints?

## Example

We have a model `User` and would like to create a `post_save` signal:

```py
# …
@receiver([post_save], sender=User)
def send_activation_email(
    sender: User, 
    instance: User, 
    # …
) -> None:
    # …
```

As you can see, I have given both `sender` and `instance` the same type hint – `User`. But they are not the same type. The first is a class, and the second is an object. So, is there a way to differentiate the two?

Comment: In Python, (almost?) all things are objects. Classes are objects and you can check in the code that `User`'s type is `type`, so that should be the type hint.

Comment: You're looking for `typing.Type` -- see https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kinds_of_types.html#the-type-of-class-objects and https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type.

Comment: @Michael0x2a Thanks! Would you care to add it as an answer? I'll accept it if you do :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is `typing.Type`.

```python
from typing import Type
# …
@receiver([post_save], sender=User)
def send_activation_email(
    sender: Type[User], 
    instance: User, 
    # …
) -> None:
    # …
```

This answer was posted for the clarity and readability thanks to a comment by @Michael0x2a.